# Time from new born child to laborer?

Tags: banished

How long do I have to wait (ingame/real time) until a new born child will become a laborer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Children advance at *age 10*, becoming either *Laborers* or *Students*.

They will only become Students if there is [a school with space](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/School_House) available. Students then become Laborers at (around) *age 17*.

Age, however, is not all that easy to pinpoint. On average, [citizens](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Citizens) will age roughly ever [2.4 seasons](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Seasons), or 5 times per "year" (which is 12 seasons).

Doing the math, on average, it's *2 years* (or *24 seasons*) per 10 "age", and *3.4 years* (or *40.8 seasons*) to age 17.